# FlutterFire FCM Notifications - IOS Issue

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase FCM to send messages to devices for my app.  When a text is sent between users, I make a request to a google cloud function, which then uses FCM to send the message to the device:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.region('us-west2').https.onCall(async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const token = req.token;
        const body = req.body;
        const title = req.title;
        const sender_user_info_id = req.sender_user_info_id;
        const sender_user_id = req.sender_user_id;
        const receiver_user_info_id = req.receiver_user_info_id;
        const receiver_user_id = req.receiver_user_id;
        const conversation_id = req.conversation_id;
    
        const payload = {
            token: token,
            notification: {
                title: title,
                body: body,
            },
            data: {
                body: body,
                sender_user_info_id: sender_user_info_id,
                sender_user_id: sender_user_id,
                receiver_user_info_id: receiver_user_info_id,
                receiver_user_id: receiver_user_id,
                conversation_id: conversation_id,
            },
            apns: {
                payload: {
                    aps: {
                        sound: 'default',
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        return fcm.send(payload).then((response) => {
            return {success: true, response: response};
        }).catch((error) => {
            return {error: error};
        });
    } catch(error) {
        return {success: false, error: error};
    }
});
```

p.s. I'm using Back4App for my backend which is why I'm making a request to a cloud function rather than firebase for FCM.

If a message is being sent to an Android device, it will be caught in either the foreground or background message handler functions, and from there I can choose whether to show the notification to the device or not:

```
  static Future<void> firebaseListenForegroundMessageHandler() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
      print('Message title: ${message.notification!.title}');
      print('Message body: ${message.notification!.body}');

      if (message.notification != null) {
        flutter_local_notifications_plugin.show(
          0,
          message.notification!.title,
          message.notification!.body,
          NotificationDetails(android: android_notif_details, iOS: ios_notif_details),
          payload: convertNotificationPayload(message)
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

However if the message is sent to an Apple device, a notification is automatically pushed to the users phone.  So once the message reaches the foreground or background message handlers, and I choose to push the notification out, 2 will be sent for every 1 message.

I would like to be able to choose if I want to show a notification for a message for Apple devices, rather than it automatically doing it for me.  Below is my file where I configure FCM:

```
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:supply_my_degree/utils/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:supply_my_degree/firebase/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:supply_my_degree/social/direct_message.dart';
import 'package:supply_my_degree/local_classes/local_conversation.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:supply_my_degree/utils/set_badge_number.dart';


// https://medium.com/firebase-developers/flutter-fcm-how-to-navigate-to-a-particular-screen-after-tapping-on-push-notification-8cb5d5111ee6


class FirebaseFCM {
  /// ****************
  /// MEMBER VARIABLES
  /// ****************
  static FirebaseFunctions cloud_functions = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'us-west2');
  static FirebaseMessaging messaging_functions = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  static FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutter_local_notifications_plugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  static AndroidNotificationChannel channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel', // id
      'High Importance Notifications', // title
      description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
      importance: Importance.max,
      playSound: true);
  static AndroidNotificationDetails android_notif_details = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id, channel.name,
      channelDescription: channel.description,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.max,
      color: Colors.blue,
      playSound: true,
      icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  static DarwinNotificationDetails ios_notif_details = const DarwinNotificationDetails();

  /// *************
  /// INIT FUNCTION
  /// *************
  static Future<void> setupFirebase() async {
    // initialize firebase
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

    // initialize notifications
    const InitializationSettings _initSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
        iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings()
    );
    
    await flutter_local_notifications_plugin.initialize(_initSettings, onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onTapNotificationAndroid);
    // for ios foreground notifications
    messaging_functions.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    // initialize foreground messages
    firebaseListenForegroundMessageHandler();

    // initialize background messages
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseListenBackgroundMessageHandler);

    // initialize message opened app handler
    firebaseOnMessageOpenedAppHandler();
  }

  /// ****************
  /// MEMBER FUNCTIONS
  /// ****************

  /// handles when app is opened via notification tap while in foreground on android
  static Future<void> onTapNotificationAndroid(NotificationResponse response) async {
    print("IN onTapNotificationAndroid");
    print(response.payload);

    // if the data isn't null, extract the important data from the notification and pass to notification handler
    if(response.payload != null) {
      try{
        navigateToPageOnNotificationTap(response.payload as String);
      } catch(e) {
        print("Error while parsing data from message.data: ");
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  /// handles showing foreground
  static Future<void> firebaseListenForegroundMessageHandler() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
      print('Message title: ${message.notification!.title}');
      print('Message body: ${message.notification!.body}');

      if (message.notification != null) {
        flutter_local_notifications_plugin.show(
          0,
          message.notification!.title,
          message.notification!.body,
          NotificationDetails(android: android_notif_details, iOS: ios_notif_details),
          payload: convertNotificationPayload(message)
        );
      }
    });
  }

  /// handles when a message opens the app
  ///   iOS: foreground, background
  ///   Android: background
  static Future<void> firebaseOnMessageOpenedAppHandler() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("in firebaseOnMessageOpenedAppHandler");
      print(message);

      // if the data isn't null, extract the important data from the notification and pass to notification handler
      if(message.data != null) {
        try {
          navigateToPageOnNotificationTap(convertNotificationPayload(message));
        } catch(e) {
          print("Error while parsing data from message.data: ");
          print(e);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /// gets the apps registration token, needed to send notifications to this specific device
  static Future<String?> getFCMToken() async {
    return await messaging_functions.getToken();
  }

  /// asks the user to send notifications
  static Future<void> askForNotificationPermissions() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging_functions.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

  /// subscription that listens for a new fcm token to be created
  static void listenNewFCMToken() {
    messaging_functions.onTokenRefresh.listen((fcmToken) {
      // if there is a logged in user, update their registration token
      if (globals.GlobalVars().local_user != null) {
        globals.GlobalVars().local_user?.setRegistrationToken = fcmToken;
        globals.GlobalVars().local_user?.updateRegistrationToken(fcmToken);
      }
    }).onError((error) {
      print("ERROR: Error getting new application token: ");
      print(error);
    });
  }

  /// given a notification payload, this navigates the user to the correct screen after a tap
  static Future<void> navigateToPageOnNotificationTap(String payload) async {
    List<String> split_payload = payload.split(' ');

    // check if there is a logged in user
    if(globals.GlobalVars().local_user != null) {
      // if there is, wait for their social home data to be retrieved
      await globals.GlobalVars().local_user!.socialHomeInitFinished;
      localConversation? local_conversation = globals.GlobalVars().local_user?.filterConversationsForReceivingUser(split_payload[1], split_payload[0]);
      if(local_conversation != null) {
        await local_conversation.data_retrieved_;
        globals.GlobalVars().navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(DirectMessage.route_name, arguments: {
          'local_user': globals.GlobalVars().local_user,
          'local_conversation': local_conversation
        });
      }
    }
  }

  /// sends request to google cloud function, which uses FCM to send notification to users phone
  static Future<bool> sendNotification({
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required String token,
    required String sender_user_info_id,
    required String sender_user_id,
    required String receiver_user_info_id,
    required String receiver_user_id,
    required String conversation_id,
  }) async {
    HttpsCallable callable = cloud_functions.httpsCallable('sendNotification');

    try {
      final response = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
        'title': title,
        'body': body,
        'token': token,
        'sender_user_info_id': sender_user_info_id,
        'sender_user_id': sender_user_id,
        'receiver_user_info_id': receiver_user_info_id,
        'receiver_user_id': receiver_user_id,
        'conversation_id': conversation_id
      });

      print("Response data from /sendNotification endpoint: ");
      print(response.data);

      if (response.data == null) return false;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print('There was an error when trying to send a notification');
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
  }

  /// convert notification payload to be passed to navigateToPageOnNotificationTap
  static String convertNotificationPayload(RemoteMessage message) {
    String payload = "";
    payload = payload + message.data['sender_user_info_id'] + " ";
    payload = payload + message.data['sender_user_id'] + " ";
    payload = payload + message.data['receiver_user_info_id'] + " ";
    payload = payload + message.data['receiver_user_id'] + " ";
    payload = payload + message.data['conversation_id'];
    return payload;
  }
}

// handles background messages
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseListenBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("IN _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler");
  print(message);

  /* NOTE: Logic for showing notifs temporarily removed here */

  // see if the the conversation object already has displayed a notification,
  // if it hasn't, show one
  if(globals.GlobalVars().local_user != null) {
    String conversation_id = message.data['conversation_id'];
    List<localConversation> conversations = globals.GlobalVars().local_user!.getConversations;
    for(int i=0; i<conversations.length; i++) {
      if(conversations[i].getObjectID == conversation_id && !conversations[i].badge_icon_incremented) {
        incrementBadgeNumber();
        conversations[i].updateBadgeIconStatus(true);
      }
    }
  }
  return;
}
```